# Laravels Artisan::call('migrate:status') as json response

Tags: json, laravel-5, controller, migrate, artisan-migrate

I want to get the migration status of my laravel app in a controller as json response and I try

```
$migratiorns = \Artisan::call('migrate:status');
return response()->json($migratiorns);
```

but `\Artisan::call` returns an integer `0`.

What should I use for my case to get the desired response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is quite old but I got the same problem and didn't find any solution so I made a little helper function to get pending migrations on the fly, maybe it will help someone else:

```
function getPendingMigration($migrationsFolderPath = false, $toJson = false)
{
    $migrationsFolderPath = $migrationsFolderPath ?: database_path('/migrations');
    $migrations = app('migrator')->getMigrationFiles($migrationsFolderPath);
    $pendingMigrations = [];
    foreach ($migrations as $migration => $fullpath){
        if(!\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table('migrations')->where('migration', $migration)->exists())
            array_push($pendingMigrations, $migration);
    }
    return $toJson ? json_encode($pendingMigrations) : $pendingMigrations;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of $migration will be the output you see on the command line, which is sort of a table, its basically a string value which cannot be converted to json.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is the following

```
\Artisan::call('migrate:status');
dd(Artisan::output());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here ini my console code

```
protected $signature = 'command:name {json?}';
```

ini handle function

```
public function handle()
{
    $json = $this->argument('json');
    if($json){
        $a = ['foo'=>
            ['bar', $json]
        ];
        $a = collect($a);
        $this->info($a->toJson());
    } else {
        $this->info('Display this on the screen');
    }
}
```

just run

```
php artisan command:name -json
```

will get json output